# What is the difference with these approaches in filtering and grouping a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was wondering what are the differences in the following approaches in filtering and using groupby for Pandas dataframe.

Here's the dataframe:

```
df.head()

   | category | active | value
-------------------------------
 0 |       A  |     0  |    8
-------------------------------
 1 |       B  |     0  |    4
-------------------------------
 2 |       B  |     1  |    8
-------------------------------
 3 |       E  |     1  |    8
-------------------------------
 4 |       A  |     0  |    6
```

**1. Filtering**

Is there any significant difference between using

```
df[df.active==1].head()
```

or

```
df[df['active']==1].head()
```

Both give the same result:

```
    | category | active | value
-------------------------------
  2 |       B  |     1  |    8
-------------------------------
  3 |       E  |     1  |    8
-------------------------------
  7 |       E  |     1  |    6
-------------------------------
  9 |       B  |     1  |    4
-------------------------------
 10 |       E  |     1  |    2
```

**2. Grouping**

Using

```
df.groupby('category')[['value']].sum()
```

gives

```
category | value
-----------------
      A  |   130
-----------------
      B  |   148 
-----------------
      C  |    63 
-----------------
      D  |    57 
-----------------
      E  |   107
```

But the same thing without the double square brackets around the column name to be summed

```
df.groupby('category')['value'].sum()
```

gives

```
category
A    130
B    148
C     63
D     57
E    107
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Filtering

   ```
   df[df.active==1] and df[df['active']==1] are same.
   recommend to use df['column_name'] (sometimes column names can be function names)
   ```
2. Grouping

   ```
   df.groupby('category')[['value']].sum()

   if you are using 2D list then it returns a pandas dataframe, where category column will be a column.


    df.groupby('category')['value'].sum()

    Here, it returns a pandas series with category values as index
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`df["columnname"]` and `df.columnname` are equivalent for accessing columns, only the indexing notation should be used for assigning. For the purpose in the OP, there is no difference.

`df[["columnname"]]` returns a dataframe with only one column, while `df["columnname"]` returns a series. Double bracket notation passes a list as an index, meaning you can get multiple columns at once and get a sub-Dataframe that way.